# Building a Silverlight application upload utility?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

This post is really more of a discussion if this is even possible.

There are numerous examples all over the web, but all of those are using asp.net applications and unfortunately I can't go that route. So my goal is to build an upload utility in Silverlight that can be deployed as a CRM 2011 web resource, without using anything Asp.Net related.

I have looked at the Telerik SL upload control, but it appears to require a ServiceURL handler and I'm not sure I can embed something like that within Silverlight and make it work?

I guess I'm looking for some direction here on what my options would be. I don't want to start down one path and run into a brick wall.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Your SL control can upload the bytes of the file as an attachment (in the Notes area) to the entity record.  Here is a project on CodePlex that uses SL to upload an image as an attachment:

http://crmattachmentimage.codeplex.com/

Hopefully that will get you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: I should have mentioned that the file is going to be uploaded to SharePoint. Will be creating a document library from CRM when a new iteration is created.

I will take a look at that and see if I can catch anything good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really looked into the creation of web-resources from silverlight, but considering the web-resource utility would be using the CRM SOAP end-point, I imagine you could do the same from Silverlight.

From Silverlight, you would either need to make a reference to SOAP End-Point url which can be found in the CRM client in Settings -> Customization -> Developer Resources.

Otherwise, you could use the open-source project [CrmSilverSoap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/04/26/silvercrmsoap-a-crm-soap-library-for-crm-2011.aspx) library which already has all the generated proxy classes as well as a few helper methods for connecting to the various CRM services.

In trying to work with and create the web resources, I'd have a look at the [this SDK article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.createrequest.aspx) which shows to how to use some messages for Creating Web Resources. You will need to make the required modifications to code to enable these messages to be sent via the reference soap end-point in silverlight.